# Need assistance with multi column If Statement/For Loop

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a data set that consists of 3 fields: Store , ID, and Name such as below:

[image]

The issue I have is that every "Name" under "Store Blue" does not have a middle name, which is what I need to keep the data consistent. The ideal outcome would look as such:

[image]

Without sorting my data is there a way I can impute the Name column corresponding from a different store to those Stores that fall under "Blue"?

Here is the logic, I just need help figuring out the syntax:
IF the ID for Stores under "Red" OR "Green" = the ID for Stores under "Blue",
THEN the ID for Stores under "Blue" = ID for Stores under "Red" OR "Green"
ELSE leave as is

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df['name'] = df.name.mask(df.store.eq('Blue')).groupby(df['id']).ffill()
```